# Adding AMP JS library to Magento using XML

Tags: javascript, xml

**Requirements:** 
Add

```
<script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
```

to the head of the page

**Problem:**
JS library needs to be loaded on specific pages only, so we can't just load it to the head.phtml

**Method tried to solve:** Using XML to load it into the layout:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs">
        <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
    </action>
</reference>
```

**Error:** Invalid XML

Any idea of how to add the tag and keep `custom-element="amp-carousel"` using XML?

Answer (score 0):

```
<reference name="head">
   <block type="core/text" name="google.cdn.jquery">
      <action method="setText">
        <text>
           <![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]>
        </text>
      </action>
   </block>
</reference>
```